# Renting flat while it's not ready

Tags: united-kingdom

I recently moved to a new flat in the London area in UK. During the viewing I was told everything would be ready by the time I move in. When I moved in I had the following issues:

- The flat was unregistered with the Council (up until a couple of days ago), so I couldn't move any accounts to my new address and I couldn't apply for anything that required address (including Internet).
- The Internet/TV cabling wasn't ready (still isn't).
- There was an issue with the control panel of the heating and the handyman changed the settings 2 days after I had moved to the flat to make it work.
- I wasn't given access to the electricity meters, even though I requested it on the first day and later on. I was told where I would find the electricity meters 2 weeks after I moved in, only to find hot a huge heating consumption (as a result of what the handyman had changed - that I have now reverted back).
- I can't get access to the electricity meters because they are installed inside a fast food business that is renting from the same landlord as well. So the 3 times I managed to get access was only during their working hours and after many complaints towards me.
- The doorbell isn't installed, so I am missing on all of my deliveries.
- Due to no Internet I am forced to go back to the office every day (even during this covid era). I can't use my personal data for anything other than work (at a scale I used to) since I am saving for a rainy day (that I won't be able to go to the office). My new job would be completely wfh. So this is ruining me.

The landlord doesn't seem to care at all about the issues and is replying with future plans to fix these.

Is there anything I can do legally?

Thank you!

Comment: Move out? What do the terms of your lease say?

Comment: The terms of my lease won't allow me to move out before 8 months have passed.

I was wondering if not having a doorbell, or the flat being unregistered for close to a month, or not having cables installed for telecomunications or not providing me easy access to the electrical meters is illegal.

Comment: The terms of the lease also probably say that you get specific things, like a habitable flat, access to the meter, utilities, etc. Don't just look at your obligations, look at the landlords. If they are breaking the terms, you don't have to abide by it either.

Comment: @Lev: In addition to Ron Beyer's comment, I'd also look at you local (and national as well, probably) housing regulations; housing is generally highly regulated, and so the law might grant rights or impose obligations that are not included in the text of the lease, but laws trump contracts.